# MySQL DELETE Query with derived table

Tags: mysql, derived-table

Good day all.

I am stuck on a `MySql` delete query.

Basically I need to delete the results of this `SELECT` query :

```
SELECT radcheck.* FROM
(SELECT
  permanent_users.realm,
  devices.name,
  devices.created,
  TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) AS TimeDifference
FROM
  permanent_users
  INNER JOIN devices ON devices.permanent_user_id = permanent_users.id
WHERE
  TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) > '01:30') MySubQuery
  INNER JOIN radcheck ON MySubQuery.name = radcheck.username
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
  delete radcheck from radcheck
  inner join  (SELECT
      permanent_users.realm,
      devices.name,
      devices.created,
      TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) AS TimeDifference
    FROM
      permanent_users
      INNER JOIN devices ON devices.permanent_user_id = permanent_users.id
    WHERE
      TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) > '01:30') MySubQuery on MySubQuery.name = radcheck.username
```

Comment: HI, Thak you very much for the prompt response. i get error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join (SELECT permanent_users.realm,devices.name,devices.created,TimeDiff(N' at line 1"

Comment: delete radcheck from radcheck
  inner join  (SELECT
      permanent_users.realm,
      devices.name,
      devices.created,
      TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) AS TimeDifference
    FROM
      permanent_users
      INNER JOIN devices ON devices.permanent_user_id = permanent_users.id
    WHERE
      TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) > '00:05') MySubQuery on MySubQuery.name = radcheck.username;

This works

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge. Up untill 40 minutes ago your answer was giving the error mentioned. Now that you have edited it  with the additional "from radcheck" like mine (and works) I  accept. You have been a great help and thank you so much!!

Comment: yes  .. correct  the update .(for mysql) .need  table name  and from  .. i was  out for others  job and when i have seen you comment i have update   with the table name in right place ..

Answer (score 0):

Following on frmo the hint of scaisEdge, this works

THANK YOU!!

```
delete radcheck from radcheck
  inner join  (SELECT
     permanent_users.realm,
     devices.name,
     devices.created,
     TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) AS TimeDifference
  FROM
     permanent_users
     INNER JOIN devices ON devices.permanent_user_id = permanent_users.id
  WHERE
     TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) > '00:05') MySubQuery on MySubQuery.name = radcheck.username;
```